# Is it possible to achieve 2^k vertices with subdivision modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface, displacement

I have a $2^k$ texture that I want to use together with the displace modifier. According to the docs, the displace modifier works on vertices. Thus, I should ideally have $2^k$ vertices, but subdivision surface only affects the number of faces: A single quad will be divided into 4 quads. Thus this mesh would have 9 vertices. Would it be better than to use $2^k + 1$ pixels.

$k$ could be 11 for 2048x2048, or 10 for 1024x1024, etc.

Comment: Two to the power of K is not a texture format. 2K means two kilo-pixels or two thousand pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm thinking that you mean a 2k image: 2048x2048 pixels, 2^11 pixels in any single dimension, 2^22 pixels overall.

The number of faces you get from a subdivided default plane is 2^n in a single dimension, where n is the number of subdivision iterations.  To get 2048 faces, you need 11 subdivision iterations.

The number of vertices you have in a single dimension is 1 more than the number of faces.  11 subdivisions of a default plane will leave you with 2049 vertices.

If you really want to have 2048 vertices exactly, you can get rid of a row and column by using vertex groups and a mask modifier:

[image]

Assign three vertices to a vertex group, then use that inverted vertex group to modulate a mask modifier.  Because subdivision interpolates vertex groups linearly onto created faces, the vertex weight of the next row + column will equal 1/number of verts in a single dimension, and so you will need to set a very high threshold.  0.9999 ought to work for what you're talking about.

However, there's something that you're not considering here, which is that displacement is sampled from the *center* of the texel.  For example, on a 2x2 texture, the center of the 1st texel (0,0) is actually at 0.25, 0.25, not 0,0; the center of the texel at 0,1 is at 0.25, 0.75.  Not 0,0.5, and not 0,1.  (The offset is equal to 0.5/resolution.) That means to sample the texel exactly, you need to do some math on your displacement mapping.

Really, though, this is an academic discussion, because this isn't how you want to do displacement.  If you routinely use enough subdivisions to capture all the detail of high resolution displacement maps, you will end up with scenes that are unrenderable.  If you need very high resolution displacement from your maps, set your feature set in properties/render/scene to "Experimental" and then use adaptive subdivision on your subdivision modifier.  This will subdivide on the basis of how many pixels are actually being used by the image, from the perspective and distance rendered.

Comment: Also, using a rectangular grid is not optimal. Better to use countour and gradient lines to construct the mesh. Though this will result in n-gons at local minima and maxima.